# Dependency Injection ASP.NET Core Singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

May I know what is wrong with following line of code:-

Why I can't use singleton on it?

```
services.AddSingleton<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
```

I have been getting 500 internal server error on the above code, however it is working fine with `Transient` and `Scoped`.

Comment: I have an a speculation, but in order to be sure, i will need to see the detailed exception message.

Comment: are any of `ProductRepository`'s dependencies scoped?

Comment: Why do you want it to be a singleton? It should be Transient. What does the 500 say?

Comment: I assume based on the provided pattern that the repository depends on a DbContext? Which tends to be registered as scoped. If you try to register a singleton with scoped dependencies, it may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume based on the provided pattern that the repository depends on a `DbContext`?

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository {

    public ProductRepository (MyDbContext db) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Which tends to be registered as scoped.

If you try to register a singleton with scoped dependencies, it may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests.

Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core : Service Lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft Documentiaon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes):

> It's dangerous to resolve a scoped service from a singleton. It may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests.

Now look at the following code of your `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

There is a second parameter in the `UseSqlServer` method for *Service Lifetime* whose default value is 
`ServiceLifetime.Scoped`. May be you didn't specify the second parameter so it is taking the default value `ServiceLifetime.Scoped`. That means your `DbContext` has been registered as `Scoped service`. Now if you use your `DbContext` in `ProductRepository` then your `ProductRepository` has to be resisted as `Scoped Service` too otherwise ASP.NET Core DI provider cannot resolve it.

Now If you really want to register your `ProductRepository` as `Singleton` Service then make your `DbContext` also `Singleton` as follows:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")),ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

Now it should work!

Note: I assumed that your `ProductRepository` is dependent on `DbContext`. If not then your `ProductRepository` repository must be dependent on a service which is registered as a `Scoped` Service and that's why currently you are not able to use `ProductRepository` as `Singleton`.